# Android Application open from browser No Launcher activity found

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher

Trying to run my application from browser with scheme but getting below logs if i add scheme it show below log and unable to launch app.

```
[2015-11-18 04:49:50 - app] ------------------------------
[2015-11-18 04:49:50 - app] Android Launch!
[2015-11-18 04:49:50 - app] adb is running normally.
[2015-11-18 04:49:50 - app] No Launcher activity found!
[2015-11-18 04:49:50 - app] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2015-11-18 04:49:50 - app] Performing sync
[2015-11-18 04:49:50 - app] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Nexus_S_API_17'
[2015-11-18 04:49:52 - app] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2015-11-18 04:49:52 - app] \app\bin\app.apk installed on device
[2015-11-18 04:49:52 - app] Done!
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml` as below

```
<activity
            android:name="com.holidaynumbers.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" 
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data  android:scheme="allplayer" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Tried many different ways to run application with launcher but not able to run it and can't see app icon in apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to separate intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data  android:scheme="allplayer" />
</intent-filter>
```